# How to detect if it is the first page of my site the user views?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to perform an animation on my website only if it is the user's first time on the website. I found the "first time visitor" code with `localStorage`, but I didn't get to find about this.

Comment: what do you mean by first page? you mean your website home page? If it is on home page then just add your script for animation on homepage

Comment: how about placing the javascript on the first page of the site?

Comment: @HaBo I think he means "the very first time you visit my site"... On second read, maybe he means the first time you visit his site that time?

Comment: @HaBo I mean on the first time the visitor gets to the site, not necessarily the home page.

Answer (score 10):

<kbd>**[Working FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/LXnu2/2/)**</kbd>

You can use either `cookie` or `localStorage`. Consider you have the following HTML code:

```
<div id="first">
    Welcome Visitor
</div>

<p>This is my website.</p>
```

We set the `display` of `first` element to `none`. So it will never show.

```
#first {
    display: none;
}
```

Then we check for the first time. If it is the first time, we show that element (and maybe do some animation with it):

```
// this is the first time
if (! localStorage.noFirstVisit) {
    // show the element
    // and do the animation you want
    document.getElementById('first').style.display = 'block';

    // check this flag for escaping this if block next time
    localStorage.noFirstVisit = "1";
}
```

Comment: I agree and promote your solution even if I'd use `true` instead of `"1"`.

Comment: Tx. Great!
Btw, to know more about HTML5 'localStorage'/'sessionStorage ': [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: Don't set `display` to `block` to make the content appear. The opposite of `none` is `initial`!

Answer (score 9):

I'd do the following. You won't need cookies here. Just check whether the document.referrer includes your domain. If not, the visitor just came to your domain without visiting further pages.

```
if(document.referrer.indexOf("yourdomain.com")==-1) {
 //first pageview of the session
}
```

You can also set a cookie in addition, just in case the document.referrer gets lost somewhere.

Comment: `window.location.hostname` could be used: 

`if(document.referrer.indexOf(window.location.hostname)==-1) {}`

Answer (score 2):

When the visitor visits your site, set a cookie that indicates that they have. On every page load, check if that cookie exists. If it does, then the user has been to your site before. If it doesn't exist, it's either his first visit... or they have deleted your cookie from their browser.

So if it is my first visit, the cookie shouldn't be there, and you should play the animation.

Comment: +1 If they have cookies disabled for your site, your animation will play on every. single. page. and possibly annoy them right off your site. That problem probably exists with _every_ approach to tracking the first visit.

Comment: this. also set the cookie to never expire.

Comment: My answer only accounts per window or tab, but avoids those disadvantages. This solution is the more practical concerning modern browesers and the average user, but I would like to note that mine allows for a cross browser solution no matter the setting unless the user has disabled javascript all together, and may be combined with this answer to store as a cookie if available, as well as with local storage, at least as a check for the current page allowing if the cookie or local data does not exists before setting and may also be used to notify the system that the cookie or data was not set.

Comment: The problem here is that if the visitor close the site and then reopens the site, the animation won't play.

Comment: @Naemy Not necessarily.. setting a cookie to expire when the application does should resolve that problem if you were to use a cookie. As for local storage, that would be a bit messy if you are wanting this each time a user reopens the site, but it would involve setting that flag to false on window.onbeforeunload and resetting based on my answer as to ensure that it gets set to false when a user is exiting the page or closing the browser.. Not 100% sure, but I'm fairly sure that event still runs when the browser is being closed, so it can be done

Answer (score 1):

I am providing a sample code for @Joseph the Dreamer approach

**Create and Store a Cookie**

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

**Get a Cookie Value**

```
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var c_value = document.cookie;
var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
if (c_start == -1)
  {
  c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
  }
if (c_start == -1)
  {
  c_value = null;
  }
else
  {
  c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
  var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
  if (c_end == -1)
  {
c_end = c_value.length;
}
c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
}
return c_value;
}
```

see [Cookie with Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are meaning first page viewed in this window:

```
   if (location.referrer == location.href)
   {
      // the page was opened in a new window or tab and accessed directly
   }
   else if (location.referrer.indexOf(location.hostname) == -1) 
   {    
      // The page before this one was not a page on this site
   }
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it by first page viewed in this tab ?

Comment: yes, I changed my answer to show this a bit more clearly, I wasn't paying close enough attention. The first if statement will catch if the page being viewed is the first on a tab or new window, the else catches if the referrer was from a different host. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I think it is best you use a database to track such operations.
Using local storage or cookies are browser specific. Ones the user changes his or her browser, the feature has to start again. However with databases, there is a form of persistence.
Here is what you can do with database.

- Create a table called first_timers.
- Add a column called user_email.
- Upon logging in a user, check if the user's email is in the table.
- If Yes then user is not a first timer, if no then user is a first timer.
  Always add user email to the table upon a successful logging.